# the application is in break mode visual studio 2017 c#

Tags: c#

i have principal form and some other child forms, i show around 5forms in the principal one and 3forms work perfectly exept 2 forms
when i show them and click on start button it shows me this message
"The application is in break mode".
idk why this message doesn't show up while others forms are working exept 2 forms

Comment: Try googling Break Mode: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231224(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: @user7733611 that's a VB6 link :)

Answer (score 1):

This happened because I was calling a key value from App.config, but I missed to write the key in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

this can occur because some method or constructor is inaccessible (private or internal), put the as public